# Scala: fastest `remove(i: Int)` in mutable sequence

Tags: performance, scala, scala-collections

Which implementation from `scala.collection.mutable` package should I take if I intend to do lots of by-index-deletions, like `remove(i: Int)`, in a single-threaded environment? The most obvious choice, [`ListBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html), says that it may take linear time depending on buffer size. Is there some collection with `log(n)` or even constant time for this operation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removal operators, including `buf remove i`, are not part of `Seq`, but it's actually part of `Buffer` trait under `scala.mutable`. (See [Buffers](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_6.html))

See the first table on [Performance Characteristics](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_40.html). I am guessing `buf remove i` has the same characteristic as insert, which are linear for both `ArrayBuffer` and `ListBuffer`. 
As documented in [Array Buffers](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_24.html), they use arrays internally, and [Link Buffers](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_25.html) use linked lists (that's still O(n) for remove).

As an alternative, immutable [Vector](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_15.html) may give you an effective constant time.

> Vectors are represented as trees with a high branching factor. Every tree node contains up to 32 elements of the vector or contains up to 32 other tree nodes. [...] So for all vectors of reasonable size, an element selection involves up to 5 primitive array selections. This is what we meant when we wrote that element access is "effectively constant time".

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable._
import scala.collection.immutable._

scala> def remove[A](xs: Vector[A], i: Int) = (xs take i) ++ (xs drop (i + 1))
remove: [A](xs: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[A],i: Int)scala.collection.immutable.Vector[A]

scala> val foo = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
foo: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> remove(foo, 2)
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 4, 5)
```

Note, however, a high constant time with lots of overhead may not win a quick linear access until the data size is significantly large.

Comment: there's no column in the first table for "remove"

Comment: That's why he says "I am guessing the indexed remove has the same characteristic as insert".

Comment: @Alexey Romanov I added most the answer above after @Ron pointed it out.

Comment: Thanks! Though an immutable vector is another trade-off for good old mutable implementation like [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). Apparently Scala's [LinkedList](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/LinkedList.html) does not handle deletions at all (I wonder, what does "mutable" mean then).

Comment: @incarnate — I suppose you know already, but anyway the LinkedList is mutable in the sense that `.next` can be modified, and there's an `update()` function. But [DoubleLinkedList](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList) does have a `remove()` operation.

Comment: Please revise the formulate effective constant time. http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/ScalaVectoroperationsarentEffectivelyConstanttime.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact use case, you may be able to use `LinkedHashMap` from `scala.collection.mutable`.

Although you cannot remove by index, you can remove by a unique key in constant time, and it maintains a deterministic ordering when you iterate.

```
scala> val foo = new scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,String]
foo: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,String] = Map()

scala> foo += "A" -> "A"
res0: foo.type = Map((A,A))

scala> foo += "B" -> "B"
res1: foo.type = Map((A,A), (B,B))

scala> foo += "C" -> "C"
res2: foo.type = Map((A,A), (B,B), (C,C))

scala> foo -= "B"
res3: foo.type = Map((A,A), (C,C))
```

Comment: Yeap, thanks for great suggestion. However, this approach has its own limitations (lacks `index` and does not inherit from `Seq`). But it is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `ArrayList` effectively has constant time complexity if the last element is the one to be removed. Look at the following snippet copied from its source code,

```
        int numMoved = size - index - 1;
        if (numMoved > 0)
            System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                             numMoved);
        elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work
```

As you can see, if `numMoved` is equal to 0, `remove` will not shift and copy the array at all. This in some scenarios can be quite useful. For example, if you do not care about the ordering that much, to remove an element, you can always swap it with the last element, and then delete the last element from the `ArrayList`, which effectively makes the `remove` operation all the way constant time. I was hoping `ArrayBuffer` would do the same, unfortunately that is not the case.